# Why Google not show exact meta description of my WordPress website?

Tags: wordpress, seo

Here is my website link www.amene.co

I add this description in header.php file

```
<meta name="description" content="Official AMÈNE website. Amène is a luxury loungewear label. Shop from the latest collection." />
```

but google showing this description in search result

> Newsletter Signup. You've already signed up, Thanks! Thank you for the subscription. Enter your email: Twitter Insta Facebook. Powered By: MyHosting.Com.Pk.

i also fetch my site in google webmaster tools.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add your meta description using [Yoast SEO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/)
 plugins.

Comment: i try yoast and manual method in my another WordPress web .On my another web both method working and Google show exact description.

Comment: You're putting out more than one of them due to multiple plugins adding a description, for instance the WordBooker plugin adds a description too but has an option to disable it, other SEO plugins running might be another cause.

Comment: After trying using yoast Seo i delete yoast. Now i trying using manual method. now don't have any other seo plugin in my site.

Answer (score 0):

How about request the Google to re-indexing it from the webmasters tools, that should help after you have used the seo plugins.

Comment: How long has it been since you changed the description? Sometimes, the change doesn't occur for indexing as fast as we would want it to.

Comment: around before 3 hours.

Comment: Make sure to use only one SEO plugin and request google to re-index your site. It takes time for indexing and displaying your changed meta title, description in google. And while you have the chance to edit your meta description, consider integrating the keywords too.  I'd say check back in 3-4 days.